# What do these C# code mean?

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth

I tried to modify the Wiimote Whiteboard app for my final project. but my experience in the programming language C # is very little.

I do not know what is the meaning of a few lines of code. can anyone help me?

```
Guid HumanInterfaceDeviceServiceClass_UUID = new Guid(0x00001124, 0x0000, 0x1000, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x5F, 0x9B, 0x34, 0xFB);

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = BLUETOOTH_MAX_NAME_SIZE)]

public string szName;
```

Comment: If you have very little experience in C#, surely interoping with a bluetooth device is a bad way to get into it.

Comment: I know, but I am stuck in this situation.
Therefore, I want to learn and accomplish this project.
I hope someone can help and guide me to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MarshalAs` is used for interop between managed and unmanaged code. In C#, a `string` is always `UTF-16`. In C, since there's no built-in string type, you sometimes have to hint the runtime as to what the native code is expecting (should it be ascii/unicode? char/wchar_t? on the stack/heap? null-terminated/fixed-width/both?).

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = BLUETOOTH_MAX_NAME_SIZE)]
public string szName;
```

In this case, you are explicitly telling the runtime that `szName` should be represented as a `BSTR` (with size=`BLUETOOTH_MAX_NAME_SIZE`) when it is marshaled to unmanaged code. For specifies on what exactly a `BSTR` is, see: [Eric's Complete Guide To BSTR Semantics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/12/52976.aspx)

Comment: if i have this code: const int BLUETOOTH_MAX_NAME_SIZE = 248;

what happens at the variable szName?

Comment: @EkaS Nothing yet; `sZName` is still just an ordinary `string` until it it must be marshalled to native code (this would occur if you passed `szName` to a `DllImport`'d function, at which case, it would allocate at least 248 bytes of unmanaged memory to fit a copy of that string for use with the unmanaged code).

Comment: so sZName will be marshalled when the application execute this code

[DllImport("bthprops.cpl", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr BluetoothFindFirstDevice(ref BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS SearchParams, ref BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO DeviceInfo);]

Comment: @EkaS You've got it. :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Mr. Smith for the explanation.
sorry my english is weak.

Answer (score 0):

The first line is the instantiation of a `Guid`. It is a very specific `Guid` with the values passed into it acting as the corresponding `Guid` values.

The second line is an `Attribute` that is used to specify how the variable it is applied to is marshalled between managed and unmanaged code. If the term "marshalling" is foreign to you.. [I suggest you read up on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaw10et3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to understand more.

The third line is the string variable that has the above attribute is applied to it.

Comment: if i have this code: const int BLUETOOTH_MAX_NAME_SIZE = 248; what happens at the variable szName?

Answer (score 0):

The first line is simply creating a Globally Unique Identifier (GUID)
Refer to MSDN for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx

Next, the string variable szName is declared and decorated with an attribute which defines how it should be "marshalled", i.e. de/encoded, by un-managed code.